# Kivy Screen Manager Invalid data after declaration in KV file

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm getting an Invalid data after declaration error on line 34 of my kv file.

```
'Invalid data after declaration')
ParserException: Parser: File "main.kv", line 34:  ...
   32: on_release: app.root.current = "newGame"
   33: MenuButton:
   34: text: "Load Game"
   35: on_release: app.root.current = "loadGame"
   36: MenuButton:  ...  Invalid data after declaration
```

I assume the issue has something to do with the implementation of the screen manager. I originally wrote this in pure python and it worked fine.
I rewrote the main screen using kv language, and again, it worked as expected. I converted the sub menu screens into vk language, and now I get an error. Any ideas?
Here's The python:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from plyer import vibrator

presentation = Builder.load_file('main.kv')

backgroundMusic = SoundLoader.load('sounds/intro.mp3')
buttonSound = SoundLoader.load('sounds/button.mp3')
backgroundMusic.play()

class Layout(BoxLayout): pass
class MenuLayout(BoxLayout): pass
class MenuButton(Button): pass
class MainMenuScreen(Screen): pass
class NewGameMenuScreen(Screen): pass
class LoadGameMenuScreen(Screen): pass
class TutorialMenuScreen(Screen): pass
class SettingsMenuScreen(Screen): pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager): pass

class Uranium235App(App):

    def menuButtonPressed(event):
        buttonSound.play()

        try:
            vibrator.vibrate(.125)
        except NotImplementedError: pass

    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Uranium235App().run()
```

And here's the ky file:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager

<MenuButton>:
    on_press: app.menuButtonPressed()
    size_hint_y: .125
    background_normal: "images/button.png"
    background_down: "images/buttonPressed.png"

<MenuLayout>:
    orientation: "vertical"

<Layout>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Image:
        source: "images/banner.png"

<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainMenuScreen:
    NewGameMenuScreen:
    LoadGameMenuScreen:
    TutorialMenuScreen:
    SettingsMenuScreen:


<MainMenuScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Layout:
        MenuLayout:
            MenuButton:
                text: "New Game"
                on_release: app.root.current = "newGame"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Load Game"
                on_release: app.root.current = "loadGame"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Tutorial"
                on_release: app.root.current = "tutorial"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Settings"
                on_release: app.root.current = "settings"

<NewGameMenuScreen>:
    name: "newGame"
    Layout:
        MenuLayout:
            MenuButton:
                text: "Conquest Human VS Human"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Choas Human VS Human"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Conquest Human VS CPU"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Choas Human VS Human"

<LoadGameMenuScreen>:
    name: "loadGame"
    Layout:
        MenuLayout:
            MenuButton:
                text: "Conquest Human VS Human"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Choas Human VS Human"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Conquest Human VS CPU"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Choas Human VS Human"

<TutorialMenuScreen>:
    name: "tutorial"
    MenuLayout:
        MenuButton:
                text: "Conquest Mode"
            MenuButton:
                text: "Choas Mode"

<SettingsMenuScreen>:
    name: "settings"
    Layout:
        MenuLayout:
            MenuButton:
                text: "Music"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Sound Effects"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Vibration"
                MenuButton:
                text: "Choas Human VS Human"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the bottom two `MenuButton:` lines in the `MainMenuScreen` rule indented four spaces too far.